# Alternatives to PathListBox

Tags: wpf, animation, listbox

I would like to build a carousel for selecting items from a list. It should give the user the possibility to scroll through the list by moving the mouse to the top area of the list (which should accelerate the scrolling) and the scrolling should stop when the mouse is in the middle.

Something close to is was the [PathListBox](https://www.microsoft.com/design/) from Microsoft. I tried to build the sample but the items are jumping from one end to the other one in a very strange way when I switch to the next item.

[image: A Caroursel]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/tutorials/pathlistbox/images/carousel1.jpg))</sub>

So my question is, if there is something similar in WPF / C# to build such an item-list which can be animated prettily but without the animation bugs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try these

http://wpfcarousel.codeplex.com/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/181835/WPF-Carousel-Control